# Globals!RenderingExtension in SSRS Reports in Local Mode

Tags: reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I am using SSRS Reports in loacl mode so i need to show them on a report viewer in a web project,

my problem is i want to hide some objects depend on its rendering Type Ex: Excel

But how do i do it because Globals!Rendering extension do not support in Local mode.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Pay for a third party's assemblies like GemBox to create a new Excel document from the returned byte[], then you can alter the worksheet however you want and add security.